# Open a CSV file through notepad and convert it to UTF-8 in .NET?

Tags: .net, csv, character-encoding

I am trying to batch convert quite a number of CSV files present encoding to UTF-8 through .NET

What I have been doing till now is opening the csv file one by one and selecting "all files" from the "save as/format type" dropdown box and selecting the encoding as "UTF-8" again from the dropdown box below it and then I save it (It doesn't asks to replace the original file though).

As this procedure is quite tedious, I would like to write a tiny app for it in vb.NET

All I came up with is this: `System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII,System.Text.Encoding.UTF-8)`

But thats creating an error :(

Any suggestions?
Thx

**UPDATE:** Just updated my question to use .NET's internal lib/funcs instead of using Notepad :D

Comment: Suggestion: Skip Notepad, use encoding conversion functions available in .NET.

Comment: @deceze but won't that be a little bit of experimentation? (I read somewhere on the Internet that .NET sometimes is not able to recognize the correct set of encoding/BOM unless a 3rd party lib is used like iconv) Just to be on safer side I want to stick with notepad :D

Comment: I wouldn't automate notepad with .net.  Either do the encoding thing entirely in .NET (as per deceze) or maybe you could look at automating with AutoHotkey instead. It will let you record a macro of keyboard and mouse clicks, then replay it.

Comment: @GregHNZ Thx for replying. Looks like .NET is the way to go :) But where to begin? :( I am kinda noob here especialy when it comes to file handling. Also How can I open a file at a time and loop through the available files in a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file): 
[Mozilla's charset detector](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html) or a [.NET port of it](http://code.google.com/p/chardetsharp/).
OR 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) you can find other ways people have done it.

**EDIT:**
OR adapt/use [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1173381.aspx/1)

```
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Text; 


public partial class Converting : System.Web.UI.Page

{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    { 


        string sourceDir = "C:\\test";

        string newDir = "C:\\test2";

        foreach (String sourceFile in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))

        { 
            char[] splitter = { '\\' };



            String[] str = sourceFile.Split(splitter); 
            String fname = str[str.Length - 1]; 


            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            StreamReader ReadFile = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(newDir + 
"\\new_" + fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write); 
            StreamWriter WriteFile = new StreamWriter(fs1, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            String strLine; 
            while (ReadFile != null)

            { 
                strLine = ReadFile.ReadLine(); 
                //MessageBox.Show(strLine); 
                if (strLine != null) 
                { 
                    WriteFile.WriteLine(strLine); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    ReadFile.Close(); 
                    ReadFile = null; 
                    WriteFile.Close(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thx but apart from being a noob I would go with simple ways that just gets the work done (no harm in that ..right? :D ).

Comment: btw thx for providing me the link of how other people have done the same in different ways; useful :)

Comment: You're welcomed, also found an example for ASP.NET that should be somewhat similar : http://forums.asp.net/t/1173381.aspx/1

Comment: you just saved me the trouble of typing out the code on my own. No words for now; feeling lazy :D heeee Thanks a toN :) :) I wanted to mark this and David's as the answer. Can I mark both of them? :) An example is what I needed for a start.

Comment: Don't know, but in order to vote I think you need some reputation, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) for enumerating files in a directory.

Then look at [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx) which are convenience methods you can easily use to convert encodings.

Note that if you want UTF-8 without a signature at the start of the file (U+FEFF) you need to create your encoding with

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Comment: Thx for replying :) Well I certainly have no idea about the signature at the start of the CSV file but I did read about BOM a bit. Is that what you are trying to put up here? :| Also, Will there be any difference practically if compared to manually converted file using Notepad and the one using .NET's procedure using "System.Text.Encoding" ? Such as line/char spacing, new line etc?

Comment: The signature is indeed the BOM.

Comment: PoweRoy, yes, but with UTF-8 being a endian-agnostic encoding I'm hesitant to call it BOM in that case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one shot, fire up PowerShell:

```
gci *.csv | %{ Get-Content $_ | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 "$($_.BaseName)_Encoded.csv" }
```

gci *.csv : get all csv files in the current dir and pipe the result to a "foreach" loop (%)
Get-Content of each file then pipe the result to Set-Content that does the UTF8 conversion and store the result in a file having the same base name, postfixed with "_Encoded".

Comment: Thx for the shot :D but Windows only environment no *nix (I wished if it was *nix as there are nearly zillions of articles/posts on how to do it in *nix :) but sadly not in windows)

Comment: Awesome! but will this convert all the files in the present directory? I wanted to do a batch conversion. How can I make it work in a loop for all the files present in the current directory?

Comment: Edited the post above to give some explanations. Yes, this does conversion for all files in current dir.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. gci == get child items :) But still how can i do it through .NET, it would help as I would also learn a bit of vb.NET programming. :D UPDATE: Nice explanation above(I need 15 reps at min. to mark as very very useful :(  ) ^^

Comment: Marking clickstefan's post as answer. Sry but his answer was more related to .NET. Thanks again for all the help :) Cheers, Gunther