# UTF-8: How can the reader know how many bytes a character counts?

Tags: utf-8

UTF-8 can represent each character by one byte or more. Let's suppose that I have the following byte sequence:

```
48 65
```

How can I know if it's one character represented by `48` and another character represented by `65`, or it's ONE character represented by a combination of TWO bytes `48 65`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect UTF-8 encoding (How does MS IDE do it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479143/detect-utf-8-encoding-how-does-ms-ide-do-it)

Comment: Because the [most significant bits in the first byte of a codepoint tell a UTF-8 decoder how many bytes make up a codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: Also, you should be careful with your terminology when it comes to Unicode. What you're talking about here is individual 'code points'. What you probably consider to be a character (or [grapheme cluster](http://mathias.gaunard.com/unicode/doc/html/unicode/introduction_to_unicode.html#unicode.introduction_to_unicode.grapheme_clusters)) can be made up of an arbitrary number of individual code points. For instance, the character `é` can be encoded as `U+00E9` ('LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE), or as `U+0065` (LATIN SMALL LETTER E) followed by `U+0301` (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT).

Answer (score 6):

UTF-8 was designed in such a way as to be unambiguous. Neither 0x48 or 0x65, or anything else under 0x80, are ever part of a multi-byte sequence.

The most significant bits of the first byte of a UTF-8 encoded code point will tell you how many bytes are used for it. This should be clear from the [UTF-8 Bit Distribution Table](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#page=54):

```
Scalar Value                First Byte  Second Byte Third Byte  Fourth Byte
00000000 0xxxxxxx           0xxxxxxx            
00000yyy yyxxxxxx           110yyyyy    10xxxxxx        
zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx           1110zzzz    10yyyyyy    10xxxxxx    
000uuuuu zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx  11110uuu    10uuzzzz    10yyyyyy    10xxxxxx
```

So, the worst case scenario is you jump in mid string somewhere and see a byte whose most significant bits are 1 then 0 (everything from 0x80 through 0xBF), which says it's a continuation byte. In that case, you'd have to backtrack a maximum of 3 bytes in order to determine the full sequence.