# Irregular character/text encoding issue with writing back to file

Tags: c#, text, encoding

I'm using this function to read text lines from a file:

`string[] postFileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pstPathTextBox.Text);`

Inserting a few additional lines at strategic spots, then writing the text lines back to a file with:

```
TextWriter textW = new StreamWriter(filePath);
for (int i = 0; i < linesToWrite.Count; i++)
{
    textW.WriteLine(linesToWrite[i]);
}

textW.Close();
```

This works perfectly well until the text file I am reading in contains an international or special character. When writing back to the file, I don't get the same character - it is a box.

Ex:

Before = `W:\Contrat à faire aujourd`hui\ `

After = `W:\Contrat � faire aujourd`hui\ `

This webpage is portraying it as a question mark, but in the text file it's a rect white box.

Is there a way to include the correct encoding in my application to be able to handle these characters? Or, if not, throw a warning saying it was not able to properly write given line?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file ?

Comment: Following up on @spender's comment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add encondig like this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

and

```
new StreamWriter(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried this, same result. I tried some of the other UTF encodings, however this made the entire file garbled text. I will have to probably investigate the comments and figure out how to determine the encoding or something

Comment: UTF-8 is the right decision. Change the code specifying UTF-8, erase your actual file, run your application to generate a brand new file, open the new file using Notepad++ or other good editor (notepad is not an option because it fails reading UTF-8 witch such strange symbols).  Nevertheless, if you like to use notepad in windows, then change Encoding.UTF8 for Encoding.GetEncoding(28591) (This is equivalent to iso-8859-1)

Answer (score 0):

use This , works for me

```
string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inpPath, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try UTF encoding while writing to the file as well,

```
textW.WriteLine(linesToWrite[i],Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be need to write [Single-byte Character Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374056(v=vs.85).aspx)

Using `Encoding.GetEncodings()` you can easily get all possible encoding. ("DOS" encoding are `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding`)

[image]

In your case you may need to use

```
File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM850"));
```

and

```
new StreamWriter(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM850"));
```

Bonne journée! ;)