# Android SMS unicode detect

Tags: android, character-encoding, sms, message

I would like to know how to detect what coding has been used for SENT SMS (in case I read it from "content://sms/sent"). I check all columns and I didn´t find any information about it there.
Reason why I am looking for this is to know, how many messages has been sent. I believe when it is sent as: **160 GSM** characters = **1 SMS** ; **70 Unicode** characters = **1 SMS**

***Columns:**
_id
 thread_id
 address
 person
 date
 date_sent
 protocol
 read
 status
 type
 reply_path_present
 subject
 body
 service_center
 locked
 error_code
 seen
 deletable
 hidden
 group_id
 group_type
 delivery_date
 app_id
 msg_id
 callback_number
 reserved
 pri
 teleservice_id
 link_url*

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I assume you must check BOM marker in a text if you want to relate to its encoding. Try to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file

Comment: Thank you Rob013. It seems that this solved my problem.

Comment: Good to know Michal :) I have posted my comment as answer so that you can accept and close your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but I assume you must check BOM marker in a text if you want to relate to its encoding. Try to read this answer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

the [SmsMessage.calculateLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) method does that pretty well !

1. read the message's `body` string from the sms content provider
2. throw that to `calculateLength(body, true)`
3. read the `results` :

   - `result[0]` = 'number of SMS's required'
   - `result[1]` = 'number of code units used'
   - `result[2]` = 'number of code units remaining until the next message'
   - `result[4]` = ['encoding type that should be used for the message'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#ENCODING_16BIT)

Cheers !