# How can I force to encode every string to UTF8 despite its original type?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I've already found the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h), suggesting to do as follow:

```
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(Message);  
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);  
string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

In this way I can convert a utf8-encoded string into a iso-encoded one.
I need to convert to utf8, so the conversion should be something like this:

```
byte[] utfBytes= Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8, utfBytes);
```

I'd like to convert any kind of string I recieve to Utf8. Is there a way to do a similar conversion without specifying the starting charset?
Also, is there a way to recognise the starting charset?
Becasue in VisualStudio 2012, I had some encoding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to (reliably) detect the encoding. Encoding is not stored in the `string` object, as it is always UTF-16, or in fact, in a byte representation if you working with something else.

You will need to store the charset manually and use it to make conversion into another encoding.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1025332/706456), there are couple of examples how you can *try* detecting some of the encodings.

Here is a relevant quote from [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

> **It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.**

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the original encoding as there is no reliable way of determining it. Please see [How to detect the character encoding of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file) for a detailed answer on various encodings and why they can't be automatically determined.