# Detect encoding of byte array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, utf-8, detect

Is there any way to determine a byte array's encoding in C#?

I have any string, like  **"Lorem ipsum áéíóú ñÑç"**, and I get bytes array using several encodings.

I would like a only method for detect encoding in byte array and I get string value again.

Other issue, maybe, I'll have a column in database which store BLOB (like byte array).
A string previously converted to byte array in UTF-8. Maybe another application converts a string to byte array using Unicode encoding.

In a database column there are byte arrays in several encodings. It would be very useful detect byte array's encoding. I need a way to find encoding of byte array.

Tests:

```
string DataXmlForSupport = "<support><machinename></machinename><comments>Este es el log 1 áéíóú</comments></support>";
        string DataXmlForSupport2 = "Lorem ipsum áéíóú ñÑç";

        [TestMethod]
        public void Encoding_byte_array_string()
        {
            var uencoding = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] data = uencoding.GetBytes(DataXmlForSupport);

            var dataXml = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            Assert.AreEqual(DataXmlForSupport, dataXml, "Se esperaba resultados Unicode");

            dataXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(DataXmlForSupport, dataXml, "NO Se esperaba resultados UTF8");

            var utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            data = utf8.GetBytes(DataXmlForSupport2);

            dataXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Assert.AreEqual(DataXmlForSupport2, dataXml, "Se esperaba resultados UTF8");

            dataXml = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(DataXmlForSupport2, dataXml, "NO Se esperaba resultados Unicode");

        }
```

Comment: You should fix your database to only have one encoding, or store the encoding name in a separate column.  It is not possible to reliably detect encodings.

Comment: Typically it's your job to associate the encoding with the data.  For example in most XML/HTML files one of the first things you'll see is an attribute that describes the encoding.  If the encoding is not supplied then based on the spec there is usually a default encoding which is presumed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the character encoding of a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file)

Comment: @JimDagg text file is not same a string, any fews differences I think. Anyway, maybe share knowledge both questions.

Answer (score 4):

In short, no. Please see [How to detect the character encoding of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file) for a detailed answer on various encodings and why they can't be automatically determined.

Your best solution is to convert the string from it's original encoding to UTF8 and convert that to a byte array. Then you'll know your byte array's encoding...

Comment: If I convert string to UTF8 encoding, byte array's encoding is UTF8. Anyway, how best way safely to convert string to UTF8?

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm late to the party here, but I just had a need to do this very thing and found a good way to do it:

```
byte[] data; // Populate this however you see fit with your data
string text;
Encoding enc;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(data), 
                                              detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    enc = reader.CurrentEncoding; // the reader detects the encoding for you!
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the data contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning, which is not always the case. Otherwise, it will pretty much just default to assuming it is UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Complementing other response, you could try do:

```
string str = BitConverter.ToString(byte_array);
byte[] byte_array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: This won't work since ´BitConverter.ToString(byte_array)´ will convert the array to a string with hex values.