# Is there a reliable way to determine a text file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security

I am in the process of making a web application. It allows you to upload a .txt or .log file (IIS Logs for example).

The current way I am checking if it is a .txt or .log is checking the file extension. Now I don't like this as it allows anyone to change `virus.exe` to `virus.txt` and it will upload.

How can I verify if it really is a text file? 
I am sure this is a common problem, but I can't seem to find any good solutions.

Comment: you can check the mimetype of the file

Comment: You can check the first 256 bytes of the file.

See [previous answer][1]
.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature

Comment: @user1666620: But you can't trust it.

Comment: @SLaks you can't trust the file extension either.

Comment: @user1666620 That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Open it as a text file and see if it validates according to what you are expecting. There are some [fuzzy ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file) you can check the encoding of the file as well.

Comment: @ElGavilan I would rather detect it a bit earlier than when I need to use it.

Comment: virus.exe to virus.txt is the smaller part of the problem. virus.vbs to virus.txt is worst, since vbs files **are** textual and not binary to begin with....

Comment: Check it when it is uploaded not when you need to use it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but if you change virus.exe to virus.txt you would have nothing to worry about any way because it will no longer be an executable.

Comment: Correct, but that's not the point. I want to only be able to upload text files

Comment: apart from checking extension, i would suggest to remove the execute permission of the file, which will not allow file to execute even if its an exe

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no perfect solution to this.

You can read a portion of bytes from the file and make an educated guess of the file type from that. Try reading through the answers from this SO post :

[Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)