# read unicode string from text file in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

in Windows 10 app I try to read string from .txt file and set the text to RichEditBox:

Code variant 1:

```
var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, read);
```

Code variant 2:

```
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
ulong size = stream.Size;
using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
{
    using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
    {
        dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
        string text = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
        txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, text);
    }
}
```

On some files I have this error - "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page"

I found one solution:

```
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text);
```

But with this code the text looks like question marks in rhombus.

How I can read and display same text files in normal encoding?

Comment: Are you sure, your text is UTF8 encoded?

Comment: No. Its Unicode string in codepage 1251 or 1252. As I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1) I made a port of  Mozilla Universal Charset Detector to UWP (added to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UDE.CSharp.UWP/))

```
ICharsetDetector cdet = new CharsetDetector();
cdet.Feed(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
cdet.DataEnd();
```

2) Nuget library [Portable.Text.Encoding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.Text.Encoding/)

```
if (cdet.Charset != null)
string text = Portable.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(cdet.Charset).GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
```

That's all. Now unicode ecnodings (include cp1251, cp1252) - works good ))

Answer (score 3):

Challenge here is the encoding and it depends how much accuracy you need for your application.
If you need something fast and simple you can adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding)

```
    public static Encoding GetEncoding(byte[4] bom)
    {
        // Analyze the BOM
        if (bom[0] == 0x2b && bom[1] == 0x2f && bom[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7;
        if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8;
        if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode; //UTF-16LE
        if (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; //UTF-16BE
        if (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff) return Encoding.UTF32;
        return Encoding.ASCII;
    }

    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task MyMethod()
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
        DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
        byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
        reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
        string text = GetEncoding(new byte[4] {fileContent[0], fileContent[1], fileContent[2], fileContent[3] }).GetString(fileContent);
        txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text);

        //.. 
    }
```

If you need something more accurate you should think to port to UWP a porting [to .Net](https://github.com/superstrom/chardetsharp) of  [Mozilla charset detector](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html) as already mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file)

Please note that the code above is just a sample it is missing all the using statements for types implementing IDisposable and it also should have been wrote in a more consistent way

hth
-g

Comment: Very thx. I has made UWP port of Mozilla charset detector, as you say. And use "Portable.Text.Encoding" library from NuGet. It works perfect )

Comment: I use the notepad save as ascii and I can't open it when use your code ,and all text is "?" when char is chinese.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/FontFiles/" + fileName));
        using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
        {
            while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
           }
       }
```