# C# How to read text from folder containing multiple files with Different Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, io

I have this code

```
 string poet;
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\D\", "*.TXT"))
        {
            poet += File.ReadAllText(file,????);
            poet += "\n=================\n";
        }
```

I just want to add something to this could in the question marks place to get the encoding of each file and read it correctly , I have like a million file and the encoding is different so I can't choose an encoding in the code and i have to find a way to get the encoding of each file alone >>>
thanks in advance to everyone who might save me , and I am not committed to this specif code I just want to do what I described ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the character encoding of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file)

Comment: No actually it isn't , I don't need to detect the encoding , I need the code to read each file using the appropriate encoding for it .