# C# WriteAllText writes only in Encoding UTF8 format

Tags: c#, text

I have used the code below to write the file.

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, data, Encoding.Unicode);
```

When I read the file using code below because the type of File Encoding is run time specific.

```
using (StreamReader sR = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    encoding = sR.CurrentEncoding;
}
```

I get Encoding.UTF8

I've also used the methods in [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380031/detect-the-encoding-of-a-text-file-using-c-sharp/48592382)

Can anyone suggest the working way to find the Encoding?

Thanks

Comment: `OpenText` always opens as UTF8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: A file is just a sequence of bytes. Some guesses are possible if you're not aware of the encoding (although they are just guesses), but you really should *know and specify* the encoding when attempting to open the file.

Comment: Use `var reader = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Unicode)` instead of `File.OpenText()`

Answer (score 2):

[`File.OpenText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=netcore-3.1):

> Opens an existing UTF-8 encoded text file for reading.

So it doesn't guess what encoding the file is encoded in. Even if you used `Encoding.Unicode` when writing the file, `File.OpenText` will still read it as UTF-8.

If you want to read the file in `Unicode`, you can create a `StreamReader` like this:

```
using (StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Unicode)) {
   encoding = sR.CurrentEncoding; // Unicode
   // ...
}
```

If you don't know the file encoding, then you need to [detect the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380031/detect-the-encoding-of-a-text-file-using-c-sharp/48592382).